# Slow navigation stack update

Tags: ros, navigation, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm having issues with navigation stack. The position of the robot only updates every second causing the data not to reach the robot in time and the robot crashing into walls because velocity doesn't update on time. Could anyone point me to the right parameters to set?

Kind regards,
Maciej

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227188/slow-navigation-stack-update/) by [maciejm](https://answers.ros.org/users/25237/maciejm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's okay I have found the solution using update frequencies in global and local paths. The robot follows the path less accurately but I believe after proper frequency syncing it will be fine. Good luck all.

---

Originally posted by [maciejm](https://answers.ros.org/users/25237/maciejm/) with karma: 33 on 2016-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0